# gvNIX: Recover a backup when App crashes

Tags: gvnix, gvnix-es

Which is the way to recover a gvNIX backup? I have a trouble with one command and the webApp crashes. I would like to revert to a previous version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you saved a copy with 'backup' command just unzip the generated .ZIP file.